How can I use round up function in GAMS?
I cannot use function round the value in positive variable of arr in GAMS software (MIP)
This is my current coding.
eq1.. w(i,j) =e= round(arr(i,j),2); 
How can I fix this. I am not sure how to code this or make some loop. Thank in advance.

Use an integer variable instead.

To implement
y = round(x,2)

one can do:
z - 0.5 <= 100x <= z + 0.5
y = z/100
z integer variable
 

